# Is it possible to create these type of plots (ridgeline)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was wondering if it is possible to create these type of plots with PGFPlots? I did go through all plot types in the documentation, but I didn't see anything close to this. Maybe someone has some suggestions?

Google says these are called `ridgeline` plots. Maybe there is another keyword for something close to this in PGFPlots?

[image: ridgeline]

Comment: Actually, these are just simple line plots stacked. So, it should not be a problem to create such a thing. But I don't think that `pgfplots` has something at hand. How would the data for such a plot look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stack on multiple plots on the y axis you can use the option `stack plots = y`. However, it has the limitation of only accepting graphs composed of the same number of data. If you can provide a dataset for us to base our response on, we can provide a better answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={draw=black, fill=gray!25}}
\begin{axis}[
smooth,
stack plots=y,
area style,
enlarge x limits=false,
xlabel=length (minutes),
ylabel=year,]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1.5) (2,2) (3,2) (4,1.5) (5,1)} ;
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) (4,1) (5,1)} ;
\addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (0.5,1) (1,1.5) (1.5,1) (2,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]